# How to convert json Nested String into json in dart flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to convert nested json string into json
how could i do this

`{2022: {Apr: 100.0}}` // this is my string
I/flutter ( 7168): Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)// here error comes out
I/flutter ( 7168): {2022: {Apr: 100.0}}

`jsonDecoder("jsonstring here")`// I used this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First encode String then decode it

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
 String i = "{2022: {Apr: 100.0}}";
 var i2 =  json.decode(json.encode(i));
  print(i2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the dart library `'dart:convert'` and use its method `json.decode(<your json string>)` to convert a JSON string into a JSON.

Comment: No it is giving error

Comment: Error FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)